# Pretty Smooth Moves

Tags: code-golf, math, primes

In arithmetic, an [n-smooth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number), where n is a given prime number, is mathematically defined as a positive integer that has no prime factors greater than n. For example, 42 is 7-smooth because all its prime factors are less than or equal to 7, but 44 is not 7-smooth because it also has 11 as a prime factor.

Define a *pretty smooth* number as a number with **no prime factors greater than its own square root.** Thus, the list of pretty smooth numbers can be formulated as follows:

- *(EDITED!)* 1 is a pretty smooth number, due to its complete lack of any prime factors. (Note that in the original version of this question, 1 was erroneously excluded from the list, so if you exclude it from your outputs you won't be marked wrong.)
- Between 4 (= 2<sup>2</sup>) and 8, the pretty smooth numbers are 2-smooth, meaning they have 2 as their only prime factor.
- Between 9 (= 3<sup>2</sup>) and 24, the pretty smooth numbers are 3-smooth, and can have 2s and 3s in their prime factorizations.
- Between 25 (= 5<sup>2</sup>) and 48, the pretty smooth numbers are 5-smooth, and can have 2s, 3s, and 5s in their prime factorizations.
- And so on, upgrading the criteria every time the square of the next prime number is reached.

The list of pretty smooth numbers is fixed, and begins as follows: 1, 4, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 25, ...

Your challenge is to write code that will output all pretty smooth numbers up to and including 10,000 (= 100<sup>2</sup>). There must be at least one separator (it doesn't matter what kind -- space, comma, newline, anything) between each number in the list and the next, but it is completely irrelevant what character is used.

As per usual, lowest byte count wins -- obviously, simply outputting the list isn't going to be too beneficial to you here. Good luck!

Comment: Why is **1** not pretty smooth?

Comment: Can we output the list in reverse order?

Comment: [OEIS A048098](http://oeis.org/A048098) (includes extra `1`)

Comment: @Mego "There are no pretty smooth numbers less than 4." is pretty clear. Not necessarily obvious, but definitely clear.

Comment: @viraptor It is voted as not clear not because it wasn't stated that 1 is not smooth, but because your definition and your exclusion statement contradict each other.

Comment: Sorry! This was a complete mistake, and "1" should indeed have been listed as pretty smooth. If anyone outputs the list according to the original criteria (i.e., excluding 1 from the list), they won't be marked wrong, but it would seem to me that including the 1 will cut down on answer length.

Comment: @A.Mirabeau You accepted my answer, but it is not the winning answer by the challenge criteria - muddyfish's [Pyke answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89852/pretty-smooth-moves/89872#89872) has the same length, and it was posted nearly 12 hours before mine, so it should be the winner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actually, 11 bytes

```
4╤R`;yM²≤`░
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=NOKVpFJgO3lNwrLiiaRg4paR&input=)

Does not include 1.

Explanation:

```
4╤R`;yM²≤`░
4╤R          range(10**4)
   `;yM²≤`░  filter: take values where
    ;yM²       the square of the largest prime factor
        ≤      is less than or equal to the value
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Æf>½S
³²ḊÇÐḟ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZmPsK9UwrCs8Ky4biKw4fDkOG4nw&input=)

#### How it works

```
³²ḊÇÐḟ  Main link. No arguments.

³       Yield 100.
 ²      Square it to yield 10,000.
  Ḋ     Dequeue; yield [2, ..., 10,000].
   ÇÐḟ  Filter-false; keep elements for which the helper link returns 0.

Æf>½S   Helper link. Argument: n

Æf      Compute the prime factorization of n.
  >½    Compare the prime factors with the square root of n.
    S   Sum; add the resulting Booleans.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

**1 byte thanks to Fatalize, for inspiration of another 1 byte.**

```
100^:4reP$ph^<=P@w\
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAwXjo0cmVQJHBoXjw9UEB3XA&input=&debug=on)

Takes about 6 seconds here.

```
100^:4reP$ph^<=P@w\
100                      100
   ^                     squared
    :4                   [10000,4]
      r                  [4,10000]
       eP                P is an integer in that interval (choice point),
        P$ph^<=P         P, prime factorized (from biggest to smallest),
                         take the first element, squared, is less than
                         or equal to P
               P@w       Write P with a newline,
                  \      Backtrack to the last choice point and make
                         a different choice until there is no more
                         choice and the program halts.
```

### Previous 21-byte solution

```
100^:4reP'($pe^>P)@w\
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAwXjo0cmVQJygkcGVePlApQHdc&input=&debug=on)

Takes about 6 seconds here.

```
100^:4reP'($pe^>P)@w\
100                      100
   ^                     squared
    :4                   [10000,4]
      r                  [4,10000]
       eP                P is an integer in that interval (choice point),
        P'(      )       The following about P cannot be proved:
           $pe               one of its prime factor
              ^              squared
               >P            is greater than P
                  @w     Write P with a newline,
                    \    Backtrack to the last choice point and make
                         a different choice until there is no more
                         choice and the program halts.
```

Comment: ``100^:4reP$pot^<=P@w\`` is one byte shorter, though less elegant.

Comment: @Fatalize Thanks, I golfed off another byte

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 53 bytes

```haskell
r=[1..10^4]
[n|n<-r,product[x|x<-r,x*x<=n]^n`mod`n<1]
```

I don't have time to golf this now, but I want to illustrate a method for testing if `n` is pretty smooth: Multiply the numbers from `1` to `sqrt(n)` (i.e. compute a factorial), raise the product to a high power, and check if the result is a multiple of `n`.

Change to `r=[2..10^4]` if `1` should not be output.

Comment: Not that it's any golfier, but I'm pretty sure the cube suffices (`8` requires it).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

**1 byte thanks to Jakube.**

```
tf!f>*YYTPTS^T4
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tf%21f%3E%2aYYTPTS%5ET4&debug=0)

```
tf!f>*YYTPTS^T4
             T   10
            ^T4  10000
           S^T4  [1,2,3,...,10000]
 f               filter for elements as T for
                 which the following is truthy: 
         PT          prime factorization of T
   f                 filter for factor as Y:
     *YY                 Y*Y
    >   T                greater than T ?
  !                  logical negation
t                remove the first one (1)
```

Comment: Surely Pyth has a square function? So you can replace `*dd`  with that function?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Nope, Pyth has not a square function.

Comment: that seems like kind of an oversight

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
4°L¦vyf¤yt›_—
```

**Explanation**

```
4°L¦v             # for each y in range 2..10000
      yf¤         # largest prime factor of y
         yt       # square root of y
           ›_     # less than or equal
             —    # if true then print y with newline
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=NMKwTMKmdnlmwqR5dOKAul_igJQ&input=)

Comment: `4°` is short for 10000.

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! Forgot about that one.

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, <s>58</s> <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
for k=1:1e4
if factor(k).^2<=k
disp‌​(k)
end
end
```

For each number it checks if all factors squared are not larger than the number itself. If yes, displays that number.

*Thanks to [@Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) for golfing this approach*

---

Another approach (50 bytes):

```
n=1:10^4;for k=n
z(k)=max(factor(k))^2>k;end
n(~z)
```

For each number computes whether its maximum prime factor squared is less than the number itself. Then uses it for indexing.

Comment: Your previous approach can be made shorter: `for k=4:1e4,if factor(k).^2<=k,disp(k);end;end`

Answer (score 1):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax), <s>252</s> <s>227</s> 220

Standard script format:

```
#define Q(A,B) for #A from 2 to B do{
Q(i,10000)if([i]call{params["j"];u=sqrt j;a=true;Q(k,u)a=a and((j%k!=0)or(j/k<u)or!([j/k]call{params["x"];q=true;Q(z,sqrt x)q=q and(x%z!=0)};q}))};a})then{systemChat format["%1",i]}}
```

Include the pre-processor in the compilation chain when calling eg:

- `execVM "FILENAME.sqf"`
- `call compile preprocessFile "FILENAME.sqf"`

This writes to the System Chat log, which is the closest thing SQF has to stdout

Answer (score 1):

## C, 113 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
main(a){for(;++a<10001;){int n=2,c=a;for(;n*n<=a;n++)while(c%n<1)c/=n;if(c<2)printf("%d ",a);}}
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/uDB1ig)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
T4^S#DP#X<!
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=T3%5ES%23DP%23X%3C%21)

(Link only goes up to 10^3 because 10^4 times out)

```
T4^S        -  one_range(10^4)
    #DP#X<! - filter_true(V, ^): (as i)
      P     -   factors(i)
       #X<! -  filter_true(V, ^):
        X   -   ^ ** 2
         <! -    not (i < ^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 20 bytes

```
(#~{:@q:<:%:)2+i.1e4
```

Result:

```
   (#~{:@q:<:%:)2+i.1e4
4 8 9 12 16 18 24 25 27 30 32 36 40 45 48 49 50 54 56 60 63 64 70 72 75 80...
```

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 90 bytes

```python
for i in range(4,10001):
 n=2;j=i
 while n*n<=j:
  while i%n<1:i/=n
  n+=1
 if i<2:print j
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/HHkgDD)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 97 bytes

```
b=F;for(j in 1:1e4){for(i in which(!j%%1:j)[-1])if(which(!i%%1:i)[2]==i)b=i<=j^0.5;if(b)print(j)}
```

ungolfed

```
b <- F                               #Initializes
for (j in 1:1e4){                    #Loop across integers 1..10^4
    a <- which(!j%%1:j)[-1]          #Finds all factors
    for (i in a)                     #Loop across factors
         b <- which(!i%%1:i)[2]==i   #Tests primeness
         if(b) c <- i<=j^0.5         #If prime, tests smoothness
    if(c) print(j)                   #If biggest prime factor gives smooth
}                                    #result, Prints the number.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
g#^ePT2tS^T4
```

Does not include 1.